# How can you work out how a browser has calculated the height of a container element in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a table-based page in my web application and I'm troubleshooting the layout which has become too tall especially in Firefox. The height of one of the `<tr>` elements for example is over 400px in Firefox where in Chrome it is 63px. Using the debugging tools I can see very easily what the computed height is but what I'm trying to work out is WHY it is that height so I can fix the problem. Am I missing something in the tools that would help me figure this out? Or are there other tools that can do this?

Tim

Comment: Usually the browser doesn't tell you directly why something is behaving the way it does. Especially since different browser have different 'defaults'. 

Could you give a code example, minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

If you cannot place an example code, you can look at W3 for the `<tr>` specification on how it **should** behave, sometimes this gives some insight why something works a certain way.

Comment: I have seen the light and changed the layout to use a CSS grid instead. Problem fixed.

Comment: Good to hear, but beware CSS grid isn't supported in some older browsers or needs some prefixes or have some weird quirks. As long your users use a more recent browser this shouldn't be a problem. https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid